# timestamps for sentences in Google Speech Api

Tags: google-app-engine, timestamp, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

Is there any way to get timestamps for sentences rather than words in text transcripts received from Google Speech API? I am currently implementing the following code.

```
 #this python file deals with providing word offsets for seek operations 

def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
"""Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

client = speech.SpeechClient()
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
         encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
         sample_rate_hertz=44100,
         language_code='en-US',
         enable_word_time_offsets=True)

operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
result= operation.result(timeout=6000)
# Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
# them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
for result in result.results:
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]
    print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
    print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))

    for word_info in alternative.words:
        word = word_info.word
        start_time = word_info.start_time
        end_time = word_info.end_time
        print('Word: {}, start_time: {}, end_time: {}'.format(word,start_time.seconds + start_time.nanos * 1e-9,end_time.seconds + end_time.nanos * 1e-9))


if __name__ == '__main__':

gcs_uri="gs://speechmldemo/DirtyAudioExample.flac"   
transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri)r code here
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting timestamps for sentences rather than words"? Do you need your text transcribed, or do you need something else?

Comment: @dsesto I think he gets list of sentences as results. What he needs is to get timestamp of when that sentence started and ended. But there aren't those timestamps. There are timestamps for individual words only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/RadicalDev/GoogleTextToSpeech) you could find a sample which the stereo file is split into independent channels in memory, then [auditok](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/auditok) tokenizes each channel based on values lower than a given threshold indicating silence. Each segment is sent to Google (preferably in parallel when their limits are better), and the responses are collected and sorted according to the time in which they occurred.